# Why html2text module throws UnicodeDecodeError?

Tags: python, unicode

I have problem with html2text module...shows me UnicodeDecodeError:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 
0xbe in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Example :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import html2text
import urllib

h = html2text.HTML2Text()
h.ignore_links = True

html = urllib.urlopen( "http://google.com" ).read()

print h.handle( html )
```

...also have tried `h.handle( unicode( html, "utf-8" )`  with no success. Any help.
EDIT :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print h.handle(html)
  File "/home/alex/Desktop/html2text-master/html2text.py", line 254, in handle
    return self.optwrap(self.close())
  File "/home/alex/Desktop/html2text-master/html2text.py", line 266, in close
    self.outtext = self.outtext.join(self.outtextlist)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xbe in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue; if you have a terminal encoding problem, a `UnicodeEncodeError` would be thrown, not a `UnicodeDecodeError`. Show us the *full* traceback and actual code that produces the error. Remove the `print` statement (assign the output of `h.handle(html)` to a variable instead, then print the variable, for example), and show us the traceback for that code.

Comment: Mine is 3.200.3 and I installed it with pip.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your traceback even with 3.200.3 however.

Comment: I upgraded 2014.4.5 and no use :(....Maybe it's my Xubuntu Studio...I should try with some other distro.

Comment: The last release is 2014.7.3. However, I cannot reproduce your issue with any of those versions.

Comment: I used a different URL (http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/unicode-sample.html), and can now reproduce the problem. Looks like Google produces different results based on IP address. This was with the 2014.7.3 release.

Comment: Tried with 2014.7.3 and no use...also with this URL  acts the same. I should try with other distro.

Comment: No, there is an actual problem here, but because Google served *me* a ASCII-only response I could not reproduce the issue.

Comment: Well, stackoverflow.com is showing up !!!

Comment: Some more testing shows that I also made a mistake: if the page is not decoded to the right codec, then things break. I can no longer trigger the error with the sample URL when decoded from UTF-8, for example.

Comment: @Alex sorry to comment here, I was answering your question related to regex when you suddenly deleted it. I'm not sure if you still need the answer but I'll provide you an issue I found on your regex. The parte related to your "content" could be the problem you had `(,{2}?)` when you need `((,{2})?)`. Hope to help

Comment: r'(\s*)([A-Z][a-z]*)((\s*)(\()(\s*)(.*?)(\s*)(\)))?((.*)(,,))?(.*[a-z]+\b)?'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is easily reproducable when *not decoding*, but works *just fine* when you decode your source correctly. You **also** get the error if you **reuse** the parser!

You can try this out with a known good Unicode source, such as `http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/unicode-sample.html`.

If you don't decode the response to `unicode`, the library fails:

```
>>> h = html2text.HTML2Text()
>>> h.handle(html)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/html2text.py", line 240, in handle
    return self.optwrap(self.close())
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/html2text.py", line 252, in close
    self.outtext = self.outtext.join(self.outtextlist)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Now, if you **reuse** the `HTML2Text` object, its state is not cleared up, it still holds the incorrect data, so even passing in Unicode will now fail:

```
>>> h.handle(html.decode('utf8'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/html2text.py", line 240, in handle
    return self.optwrap(self.close())
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/html2text.py", line 252, in close
    self.outtext = self.outtext.join(self.outtextlist)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You need to use a new object and it'll work just fine:

```
>>> h = html2text.HTML2Text()
>>> result = h.handle(html.decode('utf8'))
>>> len(result)
12750
>>> type(result)
<type 'unicode'>
```

Comment: Thank you Martijn....everything points to that. Obviously this module is not built with worldwide char support in mind.

Comment: @Alex: I've experimented more and discovered *why unicode input failed*. It handles Unicode just fine provided you don't first screw up the internal state.

Comment: The issue that @MartijnPieters mentioned about Html2Text object not being cleared up has been fixed.

Comment: @HuckleberryFinn: in what release would that be? I can still reproduce the issue with 2014.12.5. I don't see any exception handling in the [`close` method](https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text/blob/21b85f5dd8d68d10da5b15e16693f9eef263e52a/html2text/__init__.py#L125-L156).

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, exception handling has not been fixed, mostly because there was no report on issue tracker AFAIK, but the issue with " if you reuse the HTML2Text object, its state is not cleared up" has been fixed in [`f91a6aa292`](https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text/commit/f91a6aa2928378e89b8cdceec2f4ada5abfd9801) and [`4ef61c52ee`](https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text/commit/4ef61c52ee6b644695f8a617e75d1c7ae9f0b153) which was a memory leak that has been fixed due to its report on [#13](https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text/issues/13)

Comment: @HuckleberryFinn: right; in this context the reuse was after an exception was thrown. A simple `try: .... finally: self.outtextlist = []` should suffice, cleaning up regardless of any exceptions being thrown.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, you're right. I made the issue [#47](https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text/issues/47) on html2text issue tracker.