# Python html2text error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25bc' in position 945: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python

I have the following program. For some websites it works for others it don't because of this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25bc' in position 945: character maps to <undefined>
```

My Code:

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
import html2text

html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.spiegel.de/")
page_source = html.read()

h = html2text.HTML2Text()
h.ignore_links = True
h.ignore_images = True

text = h.handle(str(page_source))

print (text)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because encoding error, the page you consult seems to be in German, there should be some character that are not supported in ASCII which is the encoding of the output provided by html2text : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html2text

Here a solution I think : [Why html2text module throws UnicodeDecodeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755022/why-html2text-module-throws-unicodedecodeerror)